# Need help proving loop invariant (simple bubble sort, partial correctness)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, loop-invariant, proof-of-correctness

The bubble-sort algorithm (pseudo-code):

```
Input: Array A[1...n]
for i <- n,...,2 do
    for j <- 2,...,i do
        if A[j - 1] >= A[j] then
            swap the values of A[j-1] and A[j];
```

I am not sure but my proof seems to work, but is overly convoluted. Could you help me clean it up?

> Loop-invariant: After each iteration i, the i - n + 1 greatest
>   elements of A are in the position they would be were A sorted
>   non-descendingly. In the case that array A contains more than one
>   maximal value, let the greatest element be the one with the smallest index
>   of all the possible maximal values.
>
> Induction-basis (i = n): The inner loop iterates over every element of
>   A. Eventually, j points to the greatest element. This value will be
>   swapped until it reaches position i = n, which is the highest position
>   in array A and hence the final position for the greatest element of A.
>
> Induction-step: (i = m -> i = m - 1 for all m > 3): The inner loop
>   iterates over every element of A. Eventually, j points to the greatest
>   element of the ones not yet sorted. This value will be swapped until
>   it reaches position i = m - 1, which is the highest position of the
>   positions not-yet-sorted in array A and hence the final position for
>   the greatest not-yet-sorted element of A.
>
> After the algorithm was fully executed, the remaining element at
>   position 1 is also in its final position because were it not, the
>   element to its right side would not be in its final position, which is
>   a contradiction. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be inclined to recast your proof in the following terms:

`Bubble sort A[1..n]:
    for i in n..2
        for j in 2..i
            swap A[j - 1], A[j] if they are not already in order`

Loop invariant: 
let P(i) <=> for all k s.t. i < k <= n. A[k] = max(A[1..k])

Base case:
initially i = n and the invariant P(n) is trivially satisfied.

Induction step:
assuming the invariant holds for some P(m + 1),
show that after the inner loop executes, the invariant holds for P(m).

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me out a lot. I have a question though: Why did you define i < k instead of i <= k? As far as I understand the variable i refers to the state of the program before each iteration. Doesn't this only proof that A[3..n] is sorted? How would I formally proof something like that?

And another question, if you don't mind: I would proof the induction step with a paragraph of text. If I wanted to be really formal, is it right that I would need another induction inside the induction to proof that the inner loop moves the new maximum to its final position?

Comment: Hi, glad that was of some help.  It's been a while and I probably committed a fence-post error there (is the invariant what is true before the loop body has executed or after?).  Either way, the invariant essentially says "everything past this point is a (sorted) suffix of the final result".  To prove the induction step, you just need to show that the inner loop moves a maximal element to the end of the unsorted part.